# div absolutely positioned over html5 video player not capturing clicks when video is playing on ipad, ios6

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video

i have a absolute div positioned over a custom brightcove video player. 
when the video is not playing , i can capture it being clicked. however, when 
the video is playing, no clicks are getting through.

what could be the problem? could it be that brightcove player is preventingDefault for the clicks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mobile Safari does not allow any elements positioned on top of a video element to receive any mouse/touch events, *except* when the video element does not have the "controls" attribute. This has nothing to do with `preventDefault`.

If you were creating your own video element, the solution would be easy: disable native video controls on the element and build your own (or use something like videojs, jPlayer, etc.). But it's a little tricky to get Brightcove to do this is quite tricky. You need to create a custom player, which unfortunately is going to be restricted to your Brightcove account and cannot be applied generally to all Brightcove videos.

Brightcove does have some documentation on how to do this if you search for it, but be careful because when they say "chromeless player", they don't mean a player without any controls, like YouTube does. Brightcove's chromeless player still has play controls; it just doesn't have any of the extra share buttons below/above the video.